# How to view data only associated with the person logging in

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc

I have a simple ASP.NET MVC C# bookings Application.

There is lots of data in the database.

What I want to know is when a person from a certain company logs in, how can they view details related to them in the database.

For instance, I login now: click staff and all staff in the db appear and not just the staff within their company.

```
public class StaffController : Controller
{
    BookingsModel.ModelBookings db = new BookingsModel.ModelBookings();
    // GET: Staff
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        Models.staffrep staffrep = new Models.staffrep();
        var staff_ = staffrep.All().Where(b => b.Active == true);
        return View(staff_);
    }
}
```

I have now tried the following code:

```
BookingsModel.ModelBookings db = new BookingsModel.ModelBookings();
        // GET: Staff
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var staffRecord = db.Staffs.FirstOrDefault(staff => staff.StaffID == (int)Session["StaffID"]);
            var company = staffRecord.Company;
            var staffForCompany = company.Staffs;
            return View(staffForCompany);
        }
```

But seem to be getting the following error:

**LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Object get_Item(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.**

Comment: You will need a `userId` column in your table and then check for that in your `Where` statement. Something like this: `.Where(b => b.Active == true && b.UserId == userIdParameter)`

Comment: @S.Akbari There are multiple staff accessing this.  This would only work for the StaffID that I put in the parameter. I need it to happen to any staff member that logs in

Comment: This is called a "multi-tenant" scenario. There are multiple ways to achieve this.

Comment: Can you give us an indication of now you perform your authentication at the moment? How can you tell which user is logged in currently?

Comment: @MattGriffiths I have build a simple Login controller and thought if I tracked the session ID then I could track the data relative to that user.  my code is in a file here: https://onedrive.live.com/?authkey=%21AHdOPrxNsx2v01k&id=6B6225DCF15A0665%212539&cid=6B6225DCF15A0665

Comment: You would have to filter the results based on the company ID of the current user

Comment: @StephenMuecke how would I go about that?

Comment: I do not know what you models are, but obviously a employee has a `CompanyId` property, and you get the `CompanyId` of the current user and then filter employees - e.g. `.Where(b => b.Active == true && b.CompanyId = companyId)`

Comment: You need to edit you question with the relevant code (not in comments), or ask a new question

Comment: @StephenMuecke Sorry about that.  I've added it in.

Comment: Because your need to do `int staffID = (int)Session["StaffID"]; var staffRecord = db.Staffs.FirstOrDefault(staff => staff.StaffID == staffID);`

Comment: @StephenMuecke That has worked.  Thank you for your help with this.  Much appreciated!!